# How to generate a list with a loop, and put it into a variable?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am pretty new to *Mathematica* and to coding in general. I want to do a very specific thing, but I unable to do it.

Please explain in detail how I can make this work.

Here's the details on what I am trying to do:

I have the following matrix, which included two variables which are lists in themselves, to analyze these lists using loops I want to make a list of lists using a loop so that the OUTPUT of the function will be this:

```
matrix = {
  {{0, 1}, {-b3 - gain11[[1]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[1]]/m}},
  {{0, 1}, {-b3 - gain11[[1]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[2]]/m}},
  {{0, 1}, {-b3 - gain11[[1]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[3]]/m}},
  {{0, 1}, {-b3 - gain11[[2]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[1]]/m}},
  {{0, 1}, {-b3 - gain11[[2]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[2]]/m}},
  {{0, 1}, {-b3 - gain11[[2]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[3]]/m}},
  {{0, 1}, {-b3 - gain11[[3]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[1]]/m}},
  {{0, 1}, {-b3 - gain11[[3]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[2]]/m}},
  {{0, 1}, {-b3 - gain11[[3]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[3]]/m}}
}
```

As you may have noticed, it's the same list repeated 9 times, where it fetches data from two lists, from `gain11` and `gain22`, each with three elements, so that all possible combinations have been made.

I have tried to use

```
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++,
  For[j = 1, j < 4, j++, {{0, 1}, matrix = {-b3 - gain11[[i]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[j]]/m}}]]
```

but all that does is overwrite itself. I end up with only the last value.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post a *complete* working example, with at least some minimum data so readers can better assist.

Answer (score 3):

For-loops are supported in *Mathematica* so people coming to *Mathematica* from procedural languages like C and Java will feel comfortable. But For-loops should avoided. They don't fit in well into *Mathematica*'s functional programming paradigm, which means it's tricky to get them right and they produce extremely inefficient code. Better for a beginner to get off to good start by looking into [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html), which is *Mathematica*'s high-level function for constructing lists of all kinds. In your case it would go like this.

```
gain11 = {g111, g112, g113};
gain22 = {g221, g222, g223};
tabl = Table[{{0, 1}, {-b3 - i/m, -a3 - j/m}}, {i, gain11}, {j, gain22}]
```

> ```
> {
>    {{{0, 1}, {-b3 - g111/m, -a3 - g221/m}}, 
>     {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g111/m, -a3 - g222/m}}, 
>     {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g111/m, -a3 - g223/m}}}, 
>    {{{0, 1}, {-b3 - g112/m, -a3 - g221/m}}, 
>     {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g112/m, -a3 - g222/m}}, 
>     {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g112/m, -a3 - g223/m}}}, 
>    ({{0, 1}, {-b3 - g113/m, -a3 - g221/m}}, 
>     {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g113/m, -a3 - g222/m}}, 
>     {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g113/m, -a3 - g223/m}}}
> }
> ```

Now that's almost what you want, except it's a 3 x 3 matrix rather than a list of 9 elements. Not to worry. *Mathematica* has function to handle this problem which comes up often.

```
matrix = Flatten[tabl, 1]
```

> ```
> {
>    {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g111/m, -a3 - g221/m}}, 
>    {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g111/m, -a3 - g222/m}}, 
>    {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g111/m, -a3 - g223/m}}, 
>    {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g112/m, -a3 - g221/m}}, 
>    {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g112/m, -a3 - g222/m}}, 
>    {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g112/m, -a3 - g223/m}}, 
>    {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g113/m, -a3 - g221/m}}, 
>    {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g113/m, -a3 - g222/m}}, 
>    {{0, 1}, {-b3 - g113/m, -a3 - g223/m}}
> }
> ```

It can be done, of course, by combining the two steps into one.

```
matrix = Flatten[Table[{{0, 1}, {-b3 - i/m, -a3 - j/m}}, {i, gain11}, {j, gain22}], 1]
```

I broke it into two steps so you could see why there is a need to use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html)

Comment: this is exactly the answer i was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Module[{matrix = {}}, 
 For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, For[j = 1, j < 4, j++, 
   AppendTo[ matrix, {{0,1}, {-b3 - gain11[[i]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[j]]/m}}]]]; matrix]
```

or

```
Flatten[Array[{{0,1}, {-b3 - gain11[[#1]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[#2]]/m}} &, {3, 3}], 1]
```

or

```
{{0, 1}, {-b3 - gain11[[#1]]/m, -a3 - gain22[[#2]]/m}} & @@@ Tuples[Range@3, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the above one is the one i was looking for. It seems to do what i need it to do.